# How to colspan and rowspan table in html?

Tags: html, css

How can I rowspan and colspan table in html like number 10 (white color) in table in picture?

[image]

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0o1k27p6/?

Comment: Thank you, Dmitriy. It's beautiful, but I want data in those merge cell are in one cell. Could it be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making following change

```
For row 3 first td -> colspan 2
For row 4 first td -> colspan 3
```

In css,

```
for row 3 first td -> border-bottom:none;
for row 4 first td -> border-top:none;
```

In html,

```
for row 3 first td -> text 10
for row 4 first td -> empty
```

A sample fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/faj3zdge/

Comment: It would have been great if a reasoning for down vote was also added.

Comment: Thank you, nikhil. That is good, but could it use only in html? I don't want css included.

Comment: Well, we are using css to control the borders. I dont think it we can achieve this without css

Comment: Do you mean that HTML can not merge cell like that?